# java scheduleWithFixedDelay memory leak

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice

When I use ScheduledExecutorService to run a scheduled task ,I make this test . But after several hours jvm throws `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`  and  the console print `[Full GC (Ergonomics)  5099K->5099K(5632K), 0.0313980 secs]` all the time

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ScheduleExecutorTest implements Runnable{
    private String jobNmae = "";

    public ScheduleExecutorTest(String jobNmae){
        super();
        this.jobNmae = jobNmae;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("execute : "+  jobNmae);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
        long initialDelays = 4;
        long period = 2;
        service.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ScheduleExecutorTest("job1") , initialDelays,period,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        long initialDelays1 = 4;
        long period1 = 4;
        service.scheduleWithFixedDelay( new ScheduleExecutorTest("job2"),initialDelays1,period,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

[jconsole screenshot picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUKIE.png)

start with jvm params :

```
java -Xms5m -Xmx5m -XX:+PrintGC  ScheduleExecutorTest > ./output.txt
```

and here is part of output.txt

```
[Full GC (Ergonomics)  5096K->5008K(5632K), 0.0200085 secs]
[Full GC (Ergonomics)  5096K->5017K(5632K), 0.0230042 secs]
execute : job2
execute : job1
execute : job2
execute : job1
[Full GC (Ergonomics)  5096K->5029K(5632K), 0.0204813 secs]
[Full GC (Ergonomics)  5096K->5025K(5632K), 0.0289835 secs]
[Full GC (Ergonomics)  5096K->5047K(5632K), 0.0264593 secs]
[Full GC (Ergonomics)  5096K->5061K(5632K), 0.0284851 secs]
[Full GC (Ergonomics)  5096K->5073K(5632K), 0.0270874 secs]
[Full GC (Ergonomics)  5096K->5084K(5632K), 0.0258948 secs]
[Full GC (Ergonomics)  5096K->5088K(5632K), 0.0198362 secs]
[Full GC (Ergonomics)  5096K->5092K(5632K), 0.0209186 secs]
[Full GC (Ergonomics)  5096K->5092K(5632K), 0.0254468 secs]
[Full GC (Ergonomics)  5096K->5094K(5632K), 0.0225016 secs]
[Full GC (Ergonomics)  5096K->5096K(5632K), 0.0194505 secs]
[Full GC (Ergonomics)  5099K->5099K(5632K), 0.0176883 secs]
[Full GC (Ergonomics)  5099K->5097K(5632K), 0.0205154 secs]
[Full GC (Ergonomics)  5099K->5098K(5632K), 0.0206259 secs]
```

I am new to java and want to know what is the right way to use ScheduledExecutorService. thanks ahead

Comment: Run visualvm on it and look at what objects are gathering in the heap. The code itself doesn't have anything obviously wrong, except for an oversized threadpool.

Comment: thank you   . and i will adjust the code  and test it

Comment: Did you get anything?

Comment: `ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
`
this line of code has something wrong , In jvm each thread will allocate 1M memory, but jvm start up param only has 5M memory ,maybe this is the reason